# Replacing deferred.pipe with defer.then

Tags: jquery

I was going through this example http://jsfiddle.net/b3Z9f/

```
$.each(scripts , function(i, val) {
     pipe = pipe.pipe(function() {
         return  $.getScript(val, function() {
             console.log('loaded '+ val);
         });
     });
});
```

where the author has made use of pipe to chain deferred objects and execute scripts one after the other executes.

Now from jQuery 1.8, pipe is deprecated and replaced by then. I have three issues:

1. How to replace pipe with then. Is this correct?

   ```
   $.each(scripts , function(i, val) {
        pipe = pipe.then(function() {
            return  $.getScript(val, function() {
                console.log('loaded '+ val);
            });
        });
   });
   ```
2. I do not want to console.log anything in that code, just want to execute the scripts. So how do I clean up the script to simply execute scripts using defer.then?
3. Finally can someone explain line by line what's going on in the code

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can simply replace .pipe with .then. remove the console.log if you don't want it. It adds the three scripts as callbacks that get requested and executed after deferred is resolved, in order one after the other.

Comment: thanks, what about points 2 & 3?